# How to set the autocorrection and dictionary to the same language in Mac OS X Mavericks

Tags: system-settings, language

How can I change the system to stop making corrections like so:

[image]

Please notice that the two words on the left have the dotted red line indicating that they are spelled in the wrong way.

Then, if I click the option "Look up" on the contextual menu on the right, the dictionary says the word is like on the left, where it is marked with the red line indicating the wrong spelled word.

I would like to set my system to use the same dictionary on the "look up" option and auto correction options.

I also found [this post](http://osxdaily.com/2011/08/21/set-language-priority-mac-os-x-lion-auto-correct/) that may be the solution to the problem, but it seems it only applies to Lion.

Comment: Just to clarify Synonyms: serialization [American/Canadian spelling].  serialisation [noun, British, derived] so it is pending which directory you have set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are running OS X Mavericks you have to open System Preferences, click Keyboard, then click Text, if you are looking for the settings shown in the link you provided. On the right there is a drop down menu, that let you configure the language priority like mentioned in blog post.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to change the dictionary options too, it seen it is independent from the auto correction options

Comment: You have to start `Dictionary.app` and open the preferences of this app. Voilà

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences > Accessibility (OR) Dictation & Speech

Both of these regions offer the ability to change/install languages and localisations. With the preferred variation installed, you too can have like my machine - text to speak in a bogan female voice with the Australian English spelling applied to the dictionary.

EDIT (full answer)
Stating which may be the obvious, this above process unlocks languages not listed, yet potentially desired, in:

System Preferences > Language & Region > Keyboard Preferences > Text > Spelling (drop down for Automatic or by precise language)